# contradiction of straightening out theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I found the contradiction of straightening out theorem. can you check this contradiction wrong?

Straightening out Thereom.

Let $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ be an open set and lef $f:A \to \mathbb R$ be a function of class $C^p$, $p\ge1$. Let $x_0\in A$ and suppose $Df(x_0) \neq 0$. Then there is an open set $U$, an open set $V$ containing $x_0$, and a function $h:U\to V$ of class $C^p$, with inverse $h^{-1}:V\to U$ of class $C^p$, such that $f(h(x_1,...,x_n))=x_n$

let $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. then by theorem, there is a function such that $f(h(x,y))=y$
but if $y \lt 0$ then $f\lt0$. i think it is contradiction. is it wrong??

Comment: Until you specify a point $x_0$, you haven't provided a (potential) counterexample - the claims made in the theorem involve $x_0$ in an important way.

Comment: $x_0$ such as $(0,-1)$
then $Df(x_0) \neq 0$

Comment: This is not a full refutation of your counterexample, but you'll get the idea: Let $U$ be the upper half-plane $\{(x,y):y>0\}$, and let $V$ be the lower half-plane $\{(x,y):y<0\}$. Note that $V$ contains your point $x_0=(0,-1)$. Let $h:U\to V$ be the map $h(x,y)=(x,-y)$. Note that $h$ is a $C^\infty$ diffeomorphism. On the region $U$,
$$f(h(x,y))=f(x,-y)=x^2+y^2.$$
Now there is no problem because $y>0$ everywhere in $U$. The key of this theorem is that $U$, the domain of the map $h$, can be chosen to be totally different from $A$.

Comment: I think actually writing down the specific $h$ for your counterexample would be bothersome to do, but hopefully what I've written gives you some belief that it is possible.

Comment: i understood thankyou